# Can wait a click event to complete？

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 4 buttons, basically they set the value of a variable when a chess promotion needs to be made. However, I think the program flow doesn't wait for the user to make that choice. My code is like:

```
var promotion;
$('#promo-window').show();
$('#some-promotion-button').click(function() {
    promotion = some_val; // could be q, n, r, b
    $('#promo-window').hide();
});

var move = game.move({from: source, to: target, promotion: promotion});
```

Right now when the window shows, the program keeps running while the user doesn't choose a value, and another function uses that `move` which causes the error. Is there any way that I can stop the program flow until the user clicks one of the buttons so the later code could use the value of that variable?

Comment: `var game.move` is invalid syntax. If you want that to run only after a click, put `game.move` inside the handler, instead of below it? (you're also missing a `)`...)

Answer (score 0):

Handle action after click:

```
var promotion;
$('#promo-window').show();
$('#some-promotion-button').click(function() {
    promotion = some_val; // could be q, n, r, b
    $('#promo-window').hide();

    game.move({from: source, to: target, promotion: promotion});
}
```

Comment: I actually tried that and it wouldn't work. Because the code is in an event handler and there is another event handler that tries to use the ```game.move``` when the user hasn't clicked it.

Comment: Not sure what's you have on mind when speaking about "event handler and there is another event handler". Can you explain step by step what should happen during your script?

Comment: I am using [chessboardjs](https://chessboardjs.com/) and the above code is part of my ```onDrag``` function. The ```onSnapEnd``` function is triggered when the user puts down the chess piece. These are the two event handlers I mentioned above (sorry if I used the wrong word). In either my original code or the solution you mentioned the ```onDrag``` function will end and the ```onSnapEnd``` function could not find a legal move because the users hasn't made a click.

Comment: Hmm.. maybe you can try with onDrop method instead button. It looks like this method is called after end of dragging ?